# ReactJS, react-validation issue during build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, visual-studio-2017

Im trying to use net core template for react, and for validation purposes I've added react-validation package but it throws an error while starting app:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-validation/lib/build/validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classnames' in 'C:\Users\pk\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\BetHub\BetHub.UI\node_modules\react-validation\lib\build'
 @ ./~/react-validation/lib/build/validation.js 3:45-66
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
```

It seems as if it was not installed, but I've checked in node_modules an the package is there, anything Im missing?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a problem you should be asking on the npm package's open issues on github. I did a small amount of digging, and it turns out a few other people had the same problem. Their fix: Install `classnames`

```
npm install classnames --save
```

Comment: Thanks! It actually helped!

Comment: @krezeee If your question was solved, please upvote and mark this as the answer please!